# Facebook api login very slow

Tags: facebook, authentication

Can someone tell me why the facebook api login is very slow.
see http://www.deonlinefotograaf.nl/indexanders.php?action=login

takes atleast 10 seconds

code im ussing:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => 'xxxx',
'secret' => 'xxxx',
'cookie' => true,
));


$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
try {
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
error_log($e);
$user = null;
}
}

if ($_GET['logout']=='Y') {
$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(); 
header("Location: $logoutUrl"); 
exit;
}

if (!$user) {
$logurl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'email'));
header("Location: $logurl"); 
exit;
}
```

Comment: At what step does it take long? I'm in doubt someone will test your code as soon as your app requests that much permisssions.

Comment: Profile your script, something simple as microtime...

Comment: it seems when it returns after the login url to my site it waits

Comment: so the call from facebook to my server seems slow

Answer (score 1):

I have experience this issue on my website yesterday.
And I found and problem is because the server which host my website has enabled ipv6 connection.

But the ipv6 connection to Facebook can't be established for unknown reason.

20 seconds later, the connection will fallback to ipv4.

After disable ipv6 solve my problem. Hope this work on your issue, too.